# Which is better - NLog or Elmah for logging Javascript errors/info?

Tags: javascript, logging, nlog, elmah

I want to log the response from api calls in order to trace what error messages or error codes are there as it is not always that the api call gives you a 400 error only.

So it is important to log the response back from the API. NLog and Elmah are good and the popular logging packages, but I am unsure as to which one should I use? And how one is better or worse than the other?

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666473/why-would-one-use-elmah-if-the-applicatoin-is-using-nlog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone who is looking for an answer to this question -

I used jsnlog for logging the front end errors.

Here is the documentation for this - http://jsnlog.com/

Thanks